Policy gradient - future looking returns
In the policy gradient approach, one differentiates the expected reward
$$
\mathbb{E}J=\sum P(\tau;\theta) R(\tau)
$$
to obtain
$$
\Sigma R(\tau) \nabla \log P(\tau;\theta)
$$
(with some abuse of notation). This in turn is broken down to summation over single state-action transitions,
$$
\Sigma_{\tau \sim \pi(\theta)} R(\tau) \nabla P(a_i|s_i;\theta)
$$
Note that the return of the complete trajectory multiples every single state-action $(a^j_i, s^j_i)$ transitions belonging to trajectory $\tau^j=
(s^j_0,a^j_0, s^j_1, a^j_1, ... s^j_n)$.
Usually, here comes a hand waving part that, for each state $s^j_i$ replaces the full return $R(\tau^j)$ with the future returns from this state. Rather than
\begin{align}
 \Sigma_{\tau^j,\{(a^j_i,s^j_i)\}} R(\tau) \nabla \log P(a_i|s_i;\theta) \quad (1)
\end{align}
The standard form dictates:
\begin{align}
\Sigma_{\tau^j,{a^j_i,s^j_i}} R_i^j \nabla \log P(a_i|s_i;\theta) \quad    (2)
\end{align}
with
$$
R_i^j=\Sigma_{i'>i} r^j_{i'}
$$
are the sum of rewards $r^j_{i'}$ collected at state-action transition $i$.
I'm looking for either a rigorous explanation showing these two forms are equivalent, or an explanation of the different setups and assumptions that leads to Eq (2) rather than Eq (1).

you can probably find them in the Sutton&Barto book or in the notes of one of the first lecture of the RL course from Berkeley
